# Should I sanitize my keg posts every time I attach a quick disconnect?

Tags: kegging, sanitation

Whenever I need to attach a disconnect to my kegs to take a sample I first spray the disconnect and post down with star san. After I have taken a sample and removed the disconnect I spray the post down one more time.

This is pretty tedious. Is this over kill? Will my beer survive to live another glorious tasty day if I skip this practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bad idea. When flowing, the post is pushed down, then liquid covers the whole head of the post.  If that head was previously exposed to the world, and/or has dried-up beer on it from previous use, then that can get into your serving lines, glass, growler, bottles, &c.

If you have a spray bottle of star-san at the ready, it shouldn't be that tedious to do.

Comment: Hmm, do you think it could contaminate the contents of the keg?

Comment: Are you asking if the star-San can contaminate? No. As I understand it, in the presence of massive amounts of organic material it quickly loses effectiveness.

Comment: @fthinker, your beer-out should not infect the beer in the keg, but your gas-in might. Use the spray bottle as recommended. Not only does it clean, but you have a bit of lubrication for get the connectors on more easily.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer, yes you should.  Longer answer, I often don't and haven't had any problems.  Like many things in brewing, there's best practice and then there's what you can get away with.

Comment: Thanks. I've given the answer to jsled as his answer was a little more detailed, but you really deserve it as well.

Comment: Keep in mind the risk is generally low in homebrewing.  Contaminating a $50 batch is tragic but not back breaking.  In a brewery, the downside, while still tragic is much more significant financially.